# Send message from website to gmail account using phpmailer

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I downloaded php mailer and add Contactformhandler.php file with below coding. But message service from my website is not working well. Please help me out.

I am getting the error- ( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in C:\wamp\www\carlmckever.com\ContactFormHandler.php on line 4
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0008  247024  {main}( )   ..\ContactFormHandler.php:0

Contactformhandler.php coding is-

```
<?php
require("mails\phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = "587";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Username = "sahil.katia7@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";

$mail->From = "sahil.katia7@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "admin";
$mail->AddReplyTo("sahil.katia7@gmail.com");
$mail->AddAddress("sahil.katia7@gmail.com");
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "Test message sent using the PHPMailer component";
$mail->Body = "This is a test message.";
if(!$mail->send()) { echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo; } else { echo "Message has been sent successfully"; }
header('location:index.html');
?>
```

Htmlcontactformcoding-

```
<!---ContactFormSection-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div class="boxed-grey">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <form action="ContactFormHandler.php" method="post">
                                        <label for="name">
                                            Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required="required" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email">
                                            Email Address</label>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                 <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                                </span>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required="required" /></div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="name">
                                            Message</label>
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="9" cols="25" required="required"
                                      placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-skin pull-right" id="btnContactUs">
                                        Send Message</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: error message seem clear to me

Comment: Yes, it is also clear to me. But everything is fine

Comment: if it was fine you would not  get the error - so um, its not

Comment: how should I approach this problem?

Comment: I suspect an assignment question since it's identical to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345234/send-message-from-website-to-gmail-using-php-mailer) - do your own work! You've based your code on an obsolete example, you're using an old version of PHPMailer, you've not read the docs, and you're hiding debug output with your redirect. I have little sympathy.

Comment: Lol!.. Assumed wrong. I have working website carlmckever.com

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't understand Windows paths:

```
require("mails\phpmailer.php");
              ^---
```

That's just an escaped `p`, which means nothing to php, so you're effectively doing

```
require("mailsphpmailer.php");
```

which you're being told, properly, doesn't exist.

Try

```
require("mails/phpmailer.php");
```

instead. note the `/`...